# Droplink source query breaks with templateid or templatename

Tags: templates, sitecore-query

I have a few fields in a template, and two of them have template name restrictions. Using the restriction, I get 0 results, and when removed I get all the items I want (plus others I don't)

**With templatename or templateid filter:**

[image]

**Without filter:**

[image]

**My drop-link source:**

```
query:/sitecore/content/Americas/SmartSite/Data/Navigation//*[@@templatename='Navigation Items']
```

I've tried replacing template name with `templateid` and I get the same result.  This only happens in the QA environment, not DEV or local.

When I run the query in XPath Editor I get the results that I expect.

[image]

The last suspicious thing is that after saving my template definition, the logs state that indexes were built within a second.  That would be the only fast thing about this instance

Comment: So the query you are running you ran that in QA? I assume the template is in QA too. Syntax looks correct.

Comment: You could also try using &IncludeTemplatesForSelection = Navigation Items. You would specify the path of the items. There are a few more options you can add to exclude folders as well.

Comment: You may try to rebuild the link database and search index from the control panel

Comment: @RReilley yes, XPath editor in QA

Comment: Just for testing purposes do you get the same issue if you switched the field to a multilist? I just wonder if something is off. Maybe the Sitecore versions are different in Dev vs QA.

Comment: can you compare all configs in QA with Dev, many be COnfig is disabled out.

Comment: @MStodd what is the ID value that is not in the selection list pointing to?

Comment: Try closing your browser entirely and trying again. It could be a db context issue if you have multiple tabs open.

Comment: What is the Sitecore version? If it works in DEV and not in QA, then there must be some difference. 1) Restore QA database in DEV if it still works then something wrong with webroot files. 2) Then restore App_Config folder files from QA in DEV. See if the issue is reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are experiencing some unexpected behavior with the template name restrictions in your Sitecore instance. Based on the information you provided, here are a few things you can try to help identify the root cause of the issue:

- Verify that the templates in question have the correct name and ID.
  You can do this by checking the template manager in Sitecore and
  comparing the IDs and names with those in your query and drop-link
  source.
- Check the log files in your QA environment for any errors or warnings
  related to the template restrictions or indexing. This may give you a
  clue as to what is causing the issue.
- Try using a different filter or query to see if you get the expected
  results. For example, you could try filtering on a different field or
  using a different query to retrieve the items you need.